# Go program as windows service

Tags: windows, go, windows-services

how do i make my Go program supervised by some kind of systemd in linux, the requirement are :

1. restart on crash
2. start on boot

and my Go Program also has Administrator access (via manifest file), so is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you could consider using a library like https://github.com/kardianos/service

Comment: already try that and not working, the solution is i "include" nssm inside my Go program